# The property 'isFavorite' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have got two errors for a null check. one for IsFavorite and Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')
another one for a null check for toggleFavoritestatus() and The method 'toggleFavoritestatus' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')

I have added both ?. or !. but all do not work!

here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_shop/providers/product.dart';

import 'package:my_shop/screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final product = Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false);
  return ClipRRect(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
   child: GridTile(
    footer: GridTileBar(
        title: Text(
          product.title,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          textScaler: const TextScaler.linear(2 / 3),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        leading: Consumer(
            builder: (ctx, product, _) => IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(product.isFavorite
                      ? Icons.favorite
                      : Icons.favorite_border),
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                  onPressed: () {
                    product.toggleFavoritestatus();
                  },
                )),
        trailing: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
          onPressed: () {},
        )),
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
          ProductDetailScreen.routeName,
          arguments: product.id,
        );
      },
      child: Image.network(
        product.imageUrl,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `!` after `product`: `product!.isFavorite` and `product!.toggleFavoritestatus()`

Comment: As I mentioned, I have done this and added !, but does not work.

Comment: What's the error message shown when you hover `isFavorite`?

Comment: The getter 'isFavorite' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'isFavorite', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'isFavorite'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `product` from the callback parameter is `Object` because you didn't specify the generic type when using the `Consumer`.

```dart
Consumer<Product>(
  // ...
)
```

---

When dealing with nullable value that needs to be retrieved as non-nullable, you have two options:

1. Use `!` if you're sure it's not null

   ```
   product!.isFavorite
   ```
2. Use `?.` and provide a "default case"

   ```
   product?.isFavorite ?? false
   ```

   (In this case, if `product` is `null` the value of this expression will be `false`

---

See also:

- [Consumer class](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html)
- [Working with nullable types](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#working-with-nullable-types)

Comment: I have added !  like this product!.isFavorite but the new error  is : The getter 'isFavorite' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'isFavorite', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'isFavorite'.

Comment: Have you changed the Consumer? Change it from `Consumer(` to `Consumer<Product>(`. _Please read my answer carefully!_

Comment: sorry, I forgot to change Consumer now it works even without null check and adding !

Comment: you are amazing Dhafin Rayhan!

Answer (score 1):

```
Icon(product!.isFavorite!
    ? Icons.favorite
    : Icons.favorite_border)

Use above expression and make sure product and product.isFavorite is 
not null. If it is coming from service and you are not sure about 
product and product.isFavorite is not null then you write like below.

Icon(((product!=null) && (product.isFavorite??false))
    ? Icons.favorite
    : Icons.favorite_border)
```